# Images are uploading with only 777 permission

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

We are using Ubuntu and we are uploading images through a php site. The images were uploading to this path:

```
/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6/upload
```

The "upload" folder has the permissions `755` but now its showing the below error. When we change the permissions to `777` on the upload folder, it works fine. As this is not recommended is there any solution for this?

```
Warning: 

move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6/upload/1581008501582d7f6be83fe0.85542989.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6/class.user.php on line 114
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpOCj6Kp' to '/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6/upload/1581008501582d7f6be83fe0.85542989.jpg' in /var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6/class.user.php on line 114
```

**Edit**

When I upload an image with `777`, it is displaying like this:

[image]

Comment: Who is the owner of the pictures and of the folder they're uploaded to? `ls -l` in the folder should show you.

Comment: @MikaelKjær `ls -l` showing `total 0` , i am trying with root access.....

Comment: It's not what he meant. Navigate to ` /var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6` and run `ls -l` in order to check who owns the folder. It should probably work with `766` as well. Right now I'm not sure if you need `+x` in order to create files in a directory. If your upload folder permission was `755` and it worked something about the server setup changed.

Comment: @MikaelKjær `drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Nov 17 03:04 upload`

Comment: @Seth `drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Nov 17 03:04 upload`

Comment: for other folder it showing `-rwxr-xr-x 1 name name  991 Nov 14 01:34 update`

Comment: @Seth tried with `766` not working .....

Comment: Set permissions 777 and upload a file and check who owns the uploaded file. After that set the permissions to the upload folder to the same user:group.

Comment: The folder is owned by root. If webserver isn't running with root permissions (which it shouldn't!) it can't access the files. In this case you could also use `557` to make it work but it doesn't solve your problem. Think about who should be able to read/write those files and use `chown` to change the group/user accordingly. At least one of those should be the webserver user in order to let him read the files. Check which user is used for the PHP bit in order to set it up to let it write the directory.

Comment: @MikaelKjær please check updated question , how to check `who owns the uploaded file` also `After that set the permissions to the upload folder to the same user:group` mean you want me to set again to `755` ?

Comment: @MikaelKjær after i changed to `777` i checked `ls -l` , its giving `drwxrwxrwx 2 root  root  4096 Nov 17 05:29 upload
`

Comment: @Seth `557` is working fine, how  to use `chown to change the group/user ` , how to check `which user is used for the PHP bit in order to set it up to let it write the directory` please check updated  image in question.....

Comment: @MikaelKjær there is one more owner/group except `root root` , that is `name name` how to change the `upload` folder owner/group to `name name` from `root root` ?

Comment: @Seth there is one more owner/group except `root root` , that is `name name` how to change the `upload` folder owner/group to `name name` from `root root` ?

Comment: @MikaelKjær thanks a lot for your time & patience, i found solution, when i changed owner/group to  `name name`  its working fine....

Comment: @Seth thanks a lot for your time & patience, i found solution, when i changed owner/group to  `name name`  its working fine....

Comment: @MikaelKjær please post solution as you first gave me the hint in comments.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions of the upload folder and the uploaded files with `ls -l`.
Afterwards change the folder owner to the owner of the files: `chmod user:group upload`.
Now you should be able to set 755 permissions.